# contract.methods.payFund is not a function. Unable to call any of my contract function

Tags: web3js, truffle, blockchain, dapps, react

I am unable to call any function of my contact.............. when I am printing my contract object it shows that all the functions are in the object but unable to call.

It is the output when i print my contract instance
[image]

It is a function that raised an error

[image]

Error description: -
[image]

Although i had tried to call other public functions of my contract but i got the same error.

this is my contract code
[image]

Comment: Please, provide the code as text. That will make it easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ganache or truffle node is running..
sometimes you may interact with your old instances..
run truffle migrate again and check the contract address of your abi are updated